# spring-data-solr: multiple repositories in single collection?

Tags: java, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I am trying to get a grasp of spring-data-solr.

Basic concepts like SolrDocument and Repository are straightforward enough. But how spring data solr handles multiple documents residing in the same index/collection?

For example, I have two document types - Foo and Bar.

```
<Document>
<id>foo:123</id>
<type>Foo</type>
<title>Big foo</title>
<fooStuff>foo foo foo</fooStuff>
</Document>

<Document>
<id>bar:123</id>
<type>Bar</type>
<title>Big bar</title>
<barStuff>bar bar bar</barStuff>
</Document>
```

The repositories would be defined like

```
interface FooRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Foo, String> {
}

interface BarRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Bar, String> {
}
```

and I will have instances like

```
@Autowired
FooRepository fooRepositoryImpl;

@Autowired
BarRepository barRepositoryImpl;
```

if I try to run

```
System.out.println("Foo documents: " + fooRepositoryImpl.count());
System.out.println("Bar documents: " + barRepositoryImpl.count());
```

do I get the correct counts? How can spring data solr distinguish between Foo and Bar documents in the same index?

I have a feeling it just can't, and I have to override all find/count methods for all of the repositories with my own implementations.

Comment: Same question here... Do you have a solution for this now?